# How can I create a new social User on KeyCloak via REST APIs?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have a working KeyCloak installation, and a Laravel backend that uses this to authenticate Users.
The KeyCloack server is already configured with some external ("social") identity providers.

Now I want to create, from PHP backend, new "social" Users on KeyCloak via REST API **before** they attempt to login the first time.
My goal is to create new Users on backend database with their all profile data, in order to have all the user set-up already done once the user will first login on my app.

Is there a way to do this?
Have I to create the user firsty on KeyCloak and then link it to a social provider in some way?
Or something other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two steps required:
You have to create a login-flow, that maps the SAML-User to the local user.
This must contain the "Detect Existing Broker User" and the "Automatically Set Existing User" Execution as Required.
Your Identity Providermust use this as login flow.
Then you have to configure your SAML Identity-Provider to identify the SANL-Atrribute to match the user. Feal free to ask if you need further help for this.

Comment: hi may i ask too ?. is there any github repo that show how to login via admin rest api .. for example whats the endoint i need to call to redirect to social provider ? .. thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry don't know such an example.